# How to group in Linq based on previous Value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-group

I want to group a pointcloud based on 2 conditions

1. simple on Y so I wrote `pointcloudH.GroupBy(KVP => KVP.Value.Y)` where KVP is an `KeyValuePair<string,System.Drawing.Point>`
2. and now I want to group it also by X if `X == (previousX + 1)`
   as far as I know I should us `ThenBy()` but what do I have to write between the brackets?

and here an example for a better illustration what I want to achieve

**Sample pointcloud**

```
(x|y) (1|1),(2|1),(4|1),(1|2),(2|3),(3|3),(4|3),(5|8),(9|10)
```

after **step 1.** it looks like this

```
group1 (1|1),(2|1),(4|1)
group2 (1|2)
group3 (2|3),(3|3),(4|3)
group4 (5|8)
group5 (9|10)
```

after **step 2.** it should look like this

```
group1 (1|1),(2|1)
group2 (4|1)
group3 (1|2)
group4 (2|3),(3|3),(4|3)
group5 (5|8)
group6 (9|10)
```

**current code**

```
var Hgroup = pointcloudH.OrderBy(KVP => KVP.Value.Y) // order by Y
                        .GroupBy(KVP => KVP.Value.Y) // groub by Y
                        .ThenBy(KVP => KVP.Value.X); // group by X ???
```

Comment: I think you'll want `GroupBy` rather than `OrderBy`, but it's somewhat tricky...

Comment: @JonSkeet ohh that is just a copy paste typo :) i will fix this but i'm stuck still at the same problem

Comment: @JonSkeet so it is fixed and i also added my current code snipped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think LINQ is the best tool for this kind of job, but it can be achieved. The important part is to think of the relation between your `Point.X` and the index of the relative `Point` in the `Point.Y` group. Once you realize you want to group them by `Point.X - Index`, you can do:

```
var Hgroup = pointcloudH.OrderBy(p => p.Y)
                        .GroupBy(p => p.Y)
                        .SelectMany(yGrp =>
                                    yGrp.Select((p, i) => new {RelativeIndex = p.X - i, Point = p})
                                        .GroupBy(ip => ip.RelativeIndex, ip => ip.Point)
                                        .Select(ipGrp => ipGrp.ToList()))
                        .ToList();
```

Note that this will probably perform worst than a regular iterative algorithm. My pointcloudH is an array, but you can just change the lambda to reflect your own list. Also, remove the `ToList()` if you want to defer execution. This was to ease the result inspection in the debugger.

If you want to group all points in a `Point.Y` group regardless of their index (ie order by `Point.X` as well. Add `ThenBy(p => p.X)` after the first `OrderBy` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem cannot be solved by doing 2 separate group by clauses. I have created a little sample which should work for your problem. These are the key things that are happening in the code:

- Construct 'mirror' array and insert a copy of the first item at index 0, this is used to keep track of the previous point
- Create a variable that is incremented whenever a 'chain' is broken. This is whenever the next value is not equal to the previous + 1. This way we can group by an unique key per 'chain'.

  class Program
  {
      public struct Point
      {
          public static Point Create(int x, int y)
          {
              return new Point() { X = x, Y = y };
          }

  ```
      public int X { get; set; }
      public int Y { get; set; }

      public override string ToString()
      {
          return string.Format("({0}|{1})", X, Y);
      }
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      //helper to avoid to much keystrokes :)
      var f = new Func<int, int, Point>(Point.Create);
      //compose the point array
      //(1|1),(2|1),(4|1),(1|2),(2|3),(3|3),(4|3),(5|8),(9|10)
      var points = new[] { f(1, 1), f(2, 1), f(4, 1), f(1, 2), f(2, 3), f(3, 3), f(4, 3), f(5, 8), f(9, 10) }.OrderBy(p => p.Y).ThenBy(p => p.X);;

      //create a 'previous point' array which is a copy of the source array with a item inserted at index 0
      var firstPoint = points.FirstOrDefault();
      var prevPoints = new[] { f(firstPoint.X - 1, firstPoint.Y) }.Union(points);

      //keep track of a counter which will be the second group by key. The counter is raised whenever the previous X was not equal
      //to the current - 1
      int counter = 0;

      //the actual group by query
      var query = from point in points.Select((x, ix) => new { current = x, prev = prevPoints.ElementAt(ix) })                        
                  group point by new { point.current.Y, prev = (point.prev.X == point.current.X - 1 ? counter : ++counter) };

      //method chaining equivalent
      query = points.Select((x, ix) => new { current = x, prev = prevPoints.ElementAt(ix) })
                    .GroupBy(point => new { point.current.Y, prev = (point.prev.X == point.current.X - 1 ? counter : ++counter) });

      //print results
      foreach (var item in query)
          Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", item.Select(x=> x.current)));            

      Console.Read();
  }
  ```

  }